# Best way to check status code of http response?

Tags: javascript

The question is: what is best way to check status code when get http response?
for example

```
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/').then((response)=>{
    if (response.status >= 400) {
        //handle unsuccessful request ...
    }

    // or 
    if (response.status == 200) { 
        // status ok 
    }

});
```

However, the statements have magic number. e.g. 200 or 400.
Is there best practice to avoid magic number?

Comment: They are not magical numbers, they are [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: You can define them as constants to make them more readable, but those constants will then hold “magic numbers”, which are the defined and standardized API interface though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know it's defined code. But when I develop backend service, I always use library to have http.StatusOK for 200 instead. Using number in if statement is not good for long term development.

Comment: Does browser have built-in lib for status code definition? It's very common usage. I think not good to maintain one for every developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status code is the status property on the response object. Also, unless you're using JSON with your error responses (which some people do, of course), you need to check the status code (or the ok flag) before calling json:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.status); // Will show you the status
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
});
```