# How to refresh my page when encountering a 404 error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm using MovieDB API to create a website. I'm randomly getting movie id's and generating the genres this way. However, sometimes, an id which doesn't exist gets generated and it throws a 404 error. I want to write something like: if response == 404 then rerun my code or refresh the page. I tried writing this logic many ways but I can't seem to get it to work. Thank you in advance.

```
async function getAPI(api_url) {
    const response = await fetch(api_url)
    var data = await response.json()
    var g = data.genres

    let user_genre = document.getElementById("input").value
    for (let i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        console.log(g[i].name)
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would an ID be generated that doesn't exist?

Comment: You might want to look into *why* you see the occasional 401. Taking a guess, I'd wager that the api is rate-limiting.  A more careful solution should deal with the root cause.

Comment: @danh Sorry, what does rate-limiting mean? I posted on their discussion board for an exact number of movies they have, so that my range won't go over or under their number. They haven't replied yet.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I'll be honest, I have no clue. I'm guessing some number combinations does not match the movie's ID.

Comment: @RebjaA., most services count requests per time, and will begin refusing requests when some threshold is exceeded.  It might be the cause of your 401.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to check status code of http response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456020/best-way-to-check-status-code-of-http-response)

Comment: It looks like spamming a service, don't do this, be gentle. Anyway, your function returns nothing, you don't even check the value of the input. There is no code that explains how you change or store the assembled url or something. If you want to rerun the code (like you explained) it can result in an endless loop. Especially when the url is always wrong. Read my comments at the two answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `response.ok` to check if the `fetch` succeeded, or `response.status` for the exact HTTP status.

```
const response = await fetch(api_url);
if (!response.ok) location.reload();
```

Comment: @Codebeat It answers the exact question asked ("How to refresh my page when encountering a 404 error in JavaScript"); I am not suggesting it for any specific use.

Comment: @Unmitigated Your right, removed. However be careful with this. If you have many bad urls this can take a long time. I don't see anything to store the previous assemled url so it is likely a repeat. It can be endless if the url is always wrong.

Comment: @Unmitigated Also this low level page reload behaviour doesn't belong to a function that is used by something else. This can introduce nasty bugs. Return something to indicate it failed and after this do something (or not). It is a good way to check it however not a good way to implement it (like as the example shows us).

Answer (score -1):

you can repeat function

```
async function getAPI(api_url) {
    const response = await fetch(api_url)
    if(!response.ok) {
        return getAPI(api_url)
    }
    var data = await response.json()
    var g = data.genres

    let user_genre = document.getElementById("input").value
    for (let i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        console.log(g[i].name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad example in two ways. Be careful with recursive calls, in this case it can be end up endless (url wrong, bad internet connection ect.) and can introduce an overflow (breaks code -> exception) or starts hogging the system or can result in a permanent ban of the service. Use a timer or counter to implement a timeout or better return a (unique) value the request failed. For example true and false.You use "return" to recursive call the same function however you never return any value, that is stupid. That is not the purpose of "return", this is ugly and nasty......

Comment: .....The caller of this function will never know it has failed or not. Do not try to be smart, return a value if it failed or not. Return true when it was succesful. The programmer of the calling code can decide in code what to do when failed, try it again or skip it.

Comment: codebeat, You can give the answer very easily instead of complaining

Comment: Complaining?!? I just explain to think first and do research before you post something as a solution. I cannot give an reply as answer to this because there are so many details missing like I explained before at the accepted answer.  Also at the question: "if response == 404 then rerun my code ....." 404 = not found, why he want to retry something that isn't there - "... then rerun ..." What is the reason why he wants a page reload anyway to execute a script? I cannot give an answer to an question that hide details what he is exactly doing or want to achieve.